# layout does not work in Visual Studio 2015?

Tags: c++, qt, visual-c++, qt5

I want to use layout in qt5, but In Visual Studio 2015 the layout does not work?

Here is my code:

**layout.h code**

```
#ifndef LAYOUT_H
#define LAYOUT_H

#include <QtWidgets/QMainWindow>
#include "ui_layout.h"

class layout : public QMainWindow
{
    Q_OBJECT

public:
    layout(QWidget *parent = 0);
    ~layout();

private:
    Ui::layoutClass ui;
};

#endif // LAYOUT_H
```

**main.cpp**

```
#include "layout.h"
#include <QtWidgets/QApplication>
#include <QtWidgets/QPushButton>
#include <QtWidgets/QHBoxLayout>

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    QApplication a(argc, argv);
    layout w;
    QHBoxLayout hb;
    QPushButton b("button 0");
    QPushButton b1("button 1");

    hb.addWidget(&b);
    hb.addWidget(&b1);

    w.setLayout(&hb);
    w.show();
    return a.exec();
}
```

Here is my result:
[image]

How to fix this problem?

Comment: what is layout?

Comment: @eyllanesc QHBoxLayout and QVBoxLayout

Comment: QVBoxLayout and QHBoxLayout do not have the show method.

Comment: @eyllanesc I have add header files.

Comment: @eyllanesc I don't use Qt Designer.

Comment: try with my solution

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[`QMainWindow`](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qmainwindow.html) is a special widget since it has default widgets like QStatusbar, QMenuBar, etc. When working with this widget we must place the new elements in the centralWidget.

[image]

So we must assign a widget that will be our centralWidget, and then to this we add the layouts as shown below:

```
int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    QApplication a(argc, argv);
    layout w;
    w.setCentralWidget(new QWidget);


    QHBoxLayout hb;
    QPushButton b("button 0");
    QPushButton b1("button 1");

    hb.addWidget(&b);
    hb.addWidget(&b1);

    w.centralWidget()->setLayout(&hb);
    w.show();

    return a.exec();
}
```

Comment: this solution can solve my question, but I don't fully understand why we have to use centralWidget. Could you provide me some articles or document ? I will read those information.

Comment: The first word of my answer has a link, that's the main documentation, but if you have not seen it this is: http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qmainwindow.html. Please do not forget to mark my answer as correct.